# How iterate through fasta files and modify the record id using Biopython

Tags: python, loops, biopython, fasta

I'm not a programmer and I'm new at Python, I'm trying to teach myself... So, I have a file that contains 84 entries that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
X
Y
MT
GL000210.1
```

and I would like to change the record id of all the sequences in a fasta file containing 84 records. Here is an example of fasta file:

```
>name
agatagctagctgatcgatcgatttttttcga
>name1
gagatagatattattttttttttaagagagagcgcgatcgatgc
>name2
agatgctagggc
...
```

Specifically, I want to change the first record id (that begins by ">") by the first entry of the example file above, and so on. So far I created the following script. I'm able to change the id one by one but I don't know to iterate through both files at the same time:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

records = list(SeqIO.parse("new_human_v37.fasta", "fasta"))
modified_record = records[0]
print(modified_record.id.replace("old_name", "first_entry_file1"))
```

The outputfile should looks like this:

```
>1
agatagctagctgatcgatcgatttttttcga
>2
gagatagatattattttttttttaagagagagcgcgatcgatgc
>3
agatgctagggc
...
```

Could someone give some help?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this (assuming the first file has the same number of lines as the second). If you want to generate a new file with the modified records.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
lines_file = open(my_lines_file, 'r')
fout = open("example.fa", "w")
records = list(SeqIO.parse("new_human_v37.fasta", "fasta"))

for r in records:
    line = lines_file.getline()
    r.id = line.rstrip()
    SeqIO.write(fout, r, 'fasta')


lines_file.close()
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
# first create a new file to write into ex: "fasta_file_new.fasta"
# then run the code
fasta_file_new = open("fasta_file_new.fasta", "w")
fasta_file_read = open("new_human_v37.fasta", "r")
replace_lines = open("replacer.txt", "r")


for f in fasta_file_read.readlines():
    if f.__contains__(">"):
        fasta_file_new.write(">" + replace_lines.readline())
    else:
        fasta_file_new.write(f)


fasta_file_new.close()
fasta_file_read.close()
replace_lines.close()
```

Comment: You should wrap your code example with an explanation of why this would work and what other issues may arise if any. Just adding code is not enough for an answer to be useful.

Comment: @O.D.P Okay I understand how you did it (readline vs readlines). I tried it and it worked very well. Thanks to all of you for your help.

Comment: Apesa, good to know.  This was one of my first posts on SO so I am just learning the protocol.

Comment: FRANK_B - no problem, it was fun to help out and contribute to this site.